# Android Studio: Build fails when I add a Blank Task

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the Azure Mobile Service Quick Start Project.
Imported from Eclipse to Android Studio and it builds and runs fine.

But as soon as I add a Blank Activity the Build fails:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
...
...
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define       Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/
AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

I also noticed that it added the following to the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

If I comment the addition to the gradle, I receive a whole host of errors...I am pretty sure it belongs there.

And if I remove my activity, the layout and the related menu or strings...it builds fine again.

I've worked through many posts where people received similar errors but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I've also tried, restarting, clean build and rebuild.

I would really appreciate some help...thanks

Comment: What jars are in your libs folder?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. In the libs folder I have"android-support-v4.jar", "gson-2.2.2.jar", "mobileservices-1.1.5.jar" and "thirdpartynotices.rtf"

Comment: Below my Project folder I also have an "External Libraries" folder containing "Android API 19 Platform" and "Support-Annotations-20.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

After commenting below in my app directory's build.gradle ..it worked again

```
dependencies {
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5.jar')
}
```